# Excluding template fields from indexing - difference between documentOptions exclusion vs regular exclusion

Tags: content-search, configuration, indexing, azure-search

I reducing the number of fields which get indexed in my site.

I looked at `App_Config\Include\Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config` and see the section

```
<configuration
  <sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
      <indexConfigurations>
        <defaultCloudIndexConfiguration>
          <documentOptions>
            <exclude hint="list:AddExcludedField">
              <__display_name>{B5E02AD9-D56F-4C41-A065-A133DB87BDEB}</__display_name>
```

Then I looked at `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Azure.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config` (SXA 1.7.1 config file) and found this:

```
<configuration>
  <sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
      <indexConfigurations>
        <defaultIndexConfiguration>
          <exclude hint="list:ExcludeField">
            <LearnMoreTarget_A4270003 tag="{A4270003-480F-467A-BBEA-0D1B05B28656}">{A4270003-480F-467A-BBEA-0D1B05B28656}</LearnMoreTarget_A4270003>
```

What is the difference between excluding template fields within the documentOptions section vs excluding in the defaultIndexConfiguration section?

Comment: This may be a bug. I don't see `ExcludeField` on `CloudIndexConfiguration` or `SolrIndexConfiguration`. I do see `AddExcludedField` on `IDocumentBuilderOptions`.

Comment: I see an `ExcludeField` method inside `ProviderIndexConfiguration` which is marked as `[Obsolete]`. It actually calls DocumentOptions.AddExcludedField so, in theory, should achieve the exact same thing.

Comment: I checked `9.1.0 rev. 001564` dll and `ExcludeField` is no longer there

Comment: @MarekMusielak can you put an answer to the question please, I don't want this question to get deleted due to inactivity with no answer!

Comment: @MarkGibbons here you are. Answer created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There used to be `ExcludeField` method in `ProviderIndexConfiguration` in older Sitecore version. It was just calling `DocumentOptions.AddExcludedField` as [Matthew Dresser](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/users/137/matthew-dresser) wrote in his comment.

At some point it was marked as obsolete and finally it was removed.

In Sitecore `9.1.0 rev. 001564 dll` method `ExcludeField` is no longer there.

`AddExcludedField` of `IDocumentBuilderOptions` should be used instead.